# How to find where a subroutine is being called (ida)

Tags: ida, disassembly, decompilation, decompile

I am reversing an application using IDA. I have found a small subroutine that returns information at the end of that subroutine. However I would like to see the subroutine that uses this small subroutine I found and see how it uses the information returned by the small subroutine.

I am new to this, is what Im trying to do a simple task, if so how can I do this?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It called `x-refs`. Go to the beginning of your routine, and press `ctrl+x` from disassembly view, or just `x` from the decompile view.